# I am completely lost in how to make my program loop

Tags: python, loops

This is a rock paper scissors program and I need help making it loop at least three times. Here is the code if you need it.

```
import random

#welcome
Welcome = input("welcome please choose the following options (press enter)")
while True:
#Options (Rock, Paper, Scissor) Make sure to use capital letters
player1 = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors : ")
player2 = random.choice(["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"])
print("Player 2 selected: ", player2)

#Calculating Win/Lose
if player1 == "Rock" and player2 == "Paper":
    print("Player 2 Won")
elif player1 == "Paper" and player2 == "Scissor":
    print("Player 2 Won")
elif player1 == "Scissor" and player2 == "Rock":
    print("Player 2 Won")
elif player1 == player2:
    print("Tie") 
else:
    print("Player 1 Won")
  
  while True:
    if input('Do you want to repeat(y/n)') == 'n':
        break
```

Comment: All your loop is doing is asking if you want to repeat, so it serves no purpose.  You need to put the code you want to repeat *inside* the loop, not above it.  *Think*.  You know everything you need to know to figure this out.  Just reason it out.

Comment: You don't need the second `while`. Also please check all code you post for syntactical correctness. As is it's not indented properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `for` loop inside your code,

```
import random

#welcome
Welcome = input("welcome please choose the following options (press enter)")
play = True
while play:
    for _ in range(3):
        print(f"Round : {_+1}")
        player1 = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors : ")
        player2 = random.choice(["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"])
        print("Player 2 selected: ", player2)

        
        if player1 == "Rock" and player2 == "Paper":
            print("Player 2 Won")
        elif player1 == "Paper" and player2 == "Scissor":
            print("Player 2 Won")
        elif player1 == "Scissor" and player2 == "Rock":
            print("Player 2 Won")
        elif player1 == player2:
            print("Tie") 
        else:
            print("Player 1 Won")
  
    if input('Do you want to repeat(y/n)') == 'n':
        play = False # Exit your main while loop with a flag
```

Answer (score 0):

your second while loop does not go to the next game iteration if the input is "y" (yes), nor do you exit the outer most while loop when the input is "n".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).